# Aesthetics must be either length 1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm writing a thesis in econometrics. I'm analyzing financial timeseries and I'm forecasting Value at Risk-estimates with GARCH-models.

Now, I don't consider myself as a newbie in R, but this problem is really bothering me. I've tried to look around in the forum, because I know this has been asked about before.

My problem is, that I get the following error:

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(timeDate)
library(gridExtra)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(AnalyzeTS)
library(rugarch)
library(fGarch)
library(plotly)
library(forecast)

#Initializing
env_sp500 <- new.env()
getSymbols("^GSPC", env = env_sp500 , src = "yahoo", from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-01-01"), warnings = FALSE)
sp500_close <- sp500$GSPC.Close
sp500_returns <- Return.calculate(sp500_close, method = "discrete") 
sp500_returns[1] <- 0

#GARCH specification
model.spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = 'sGARCH', garchOrder = c(1,1)),
                        mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)))
model.fit = ugarchfit(spec = model.spec, data = sp500_returns, solver = 'solnp')

#Forecasting
model.roll = ugarchroll(spec = model.spec, data = sp500_returns, 
                        n.start = 500, refit.every = 50,
                        refit.window = 'moving')
fitdist(distribution = 'norm', x = sp500_returns)
Var95_norm <- mean(sp500_returns) + model.roll@forecast$density[,'Sigma']*qdist(distribution = 'norm', p = 0.05)
ptest <- (qplot(y = Var95_norm, x = 1:500, geom = 'line')
          + geom_point(aes(x = 1:500, y = sp500_returns[507:1006], 
                          color = as.factor(sp500_returns[507:1006] < Var95_norm)))
          + scale_color_manual(values = c('gray', 'red'))
          + labs(y = 'Returns', x = 'Test Observations')
          + ggtitle('Backtesting')
          + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (506): x
```

I have absolutely no clue how to fix this issue, not even by trying the fixes from before with this issue... I have made the code as an environment - it downloads the data from yahoo. So if you copy-paste my code it should generate everything. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have all the packages installed so can't see your data - but looks like nrow(Var95_norm)==506 ? Your code will also be more readable if you do variable assignments like `as.factor(sp500_returns[507:1006] < Var95_norm)` beforehand rather than as passed parameters.

Comment: Try the code without `scale_color_manual(...`.  You specify only two colors with that `scale_` call, but it looks like `color = as.factor(sp500_returns...` is referring to many more than that.